# Which is the best method for comparing the histogram obtained after BOW?

Tags: image-processing, object-recognition, sift

1. Euclidian distance
2. Cosine similarity
3. Histogram Intersection
4. Or any other?

Consider the importance of the method in case of images. Eg, Cosine Similarity matches angle of two vectors...
What impact comparing just the angle or distance has on accuracy of BOW?
Detailed explanation is welcome!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Histogram Intersection (Pyramid Match Kernel) specifically is currently accepted as a better tool, but this doesn't generalize really. When you formulate your features or histogram computations differently, things are subject to change.

Comment: Can using Histogram Intersection for matching 128-D SIFT descriptor rather than Euclidean distance for object detection give better matches?

Comment: I guess. However, Arandjelovi and Zissermann proposed a nice technique for matching Sift with Hellinger distance and they name it RootSift. I would advise you to read through it :
http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2012/Arandjelovic12/arandjelovic12.pdf